# Trying to calculate confidence intervals for a Monte-Carlo estimate of Pi. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, confidence-interval, sampling, monte-carlo

I trying to implement the classic Monte-Carlo simulation of $\pi$ to better understand how confidence intervals (CI) decrease with more trials. There are a lot of examples of how to do the former, but I haven't been able to find a simple example of calculating the CI for it, and my method is producing CIs that seem too small to be accurate. Here's my approach:

First, (using numpy) I draw $N$ random values between -1 and 1 in a uniform distribution to represent x and y coordinates. Then I calculate the radius of all points, find the number of points within a radius of 1, and calculate $\pi$ as the number of points within the circle, divided by $N$ multiplied by 4.

```
N = 500  # trials
X = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)
Y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)
# Get radius of all points
rad_arr = np.sqrt((X ** 2) + (Y ** 2))
# Get boolean mask of points in circle
in_circle = rad_arr < 1.0  
pi_est = 4 * np.sum(in_circle) / N
```

[image: Circle Viz]

So far this is pretty standard and works perfectly. I'm now trying to understand how the confidence interval decreases as $N$ goes from 1 to 500. To do this I create the following array $\hat{\pi}_{est}$:

```
# Array of pi estimations from 1 to N
pi_est = 4 * np.cumsum(in_circle) / np.arange(1, N+1)
```

The array of the cumulative sum of points in the circle, divided by an array from 1 to $N$ creates an $N$-length array of the mean value of $\pi$ as $N$ goes from 1 to 500. Then I calculated an array of the corresponding 95% confidence interval with the following formula $1.96 \cdot \frac{\sigma_{\pi est_i}}{\sqrt{N_i}}$, where $\sigma_{\pi est_i}$ is the sample standard deviation for the estimate of $\pi$ at the $i$th step of N containing $N_i$:

```
N_arr = np.arange(N)
est_error = [1.96 * np.std(pi[:i]) / np.sqrt(i) for i in range(1, N+1)]
upper_ci = pi + est_error
lower_ci = pi - est_error
```

[image: CI Viz]

This last image looks really wrong. Specifically, the CI's are way to narrow at the beginning and not encompassing the actual value of $\pi$.

I have also tested a method where I draw $M$ draws of different $N$-point samples, so that each sample is independent from each other which produces better results:

```
M = 100
pi = np.zeros(M)
for i in range(M):
    N = i + 1  # trials
    X = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)
    Y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)
    # Get radius of all points
    rad_arr = np.sqrt((X ** 2) + (Y ** 2))
    # Get boolean mask of points in circle
    in_circle = rad_arr < 1.0  
    pi[i] = 4 * np.sum(in_circle) / N
```

[image: ![CI Viz 2]

But, the CIs still seem a little small to me, and I don't have a theoretical understanding of why this would work better then the previous method. The previous method also seems to be what all other examples of $\pi$ estimation via the Monte-Carlo method use (i.e Wikipedia's article on the [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)).

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong, and what I am misunderstanding about the Central Limit Theorem or sampling or CI calculation that is leading to this error?

**---- UPDATE 1 ---**

Based on suggestion by @EngrStudent, I've increased the sample size and did bootstrap resampling with replacement. Code:

```
M = 20000
X = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, M)
Y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, M)
    
pi = np.zeros(M)
for i in range(M):
    N = i + 1  # trials
    _X = np.random.choice(X, size=N, replace=True) 
    _Y = np.random.choice(Y, size=N, replace=True)
    # Get radius of all points
    rad_arr = np.sqrt((_X ** 2) + (_Y ** 2))
    # Get boolean mask of points in circle
    in_circle = rad_arr < 1.0  
    pi[i] = 4 * np.sum(in_circle) / N
```

For the sake of legibility, I've cropped the image to the first 50 trials.

Here's my results with a sample size of 20,000:

[image]

And here's one with 100,000:

[image]

I tried some different sample sizes, and it doesn't look to me like changing the sample size makes a difference, the CI's are looking more correct though. If this is correct, I'd still appreciate an explanation of the theory behind why this works!

Comment: Vastly too few samples.  Start at around 20,000 and go up from there.  That is going to engage the mean, not the variance.  I would consider bootstrap resampling at the time-steps in order to estimate the interval.

Comment: @EngrStudent, Thanks, I'll try it and report back. One question though, I'm able to get to an estimate of ~3.15 consistently with 2000 samples, why do I need to jump to 20,000 just to get confidence intervals?

Comment: @EngStudent, can you explain what you mean by boostrap resampling? Do you mean at every time step I resample from the N-length uniform distribution? If so, is this similar to what I'm doing in the second test I tried (running M trials where each N is sampled independently). Also what's the underlying theory of why this should work versus my incorrect method?

Comment: I was seeing "nth step" and understand, possibly wrongly, that it indicated the number of samples.  I've seen many places, not necessarily this one, that start getting really solid at higher numbers.  If you think about biased coins, how many samples do you need of all head's to prove that the coin has an average rate of showing heads above 99%?  It's like 360 samples (binom.test).  To get your next "9" requires 10x more samples (3654).  You aren't dealing with boolean events, so you are able to have more 'noise' and so my intuition tells me your samples need to be larger.  20k ~5x larger

Comment: By bootstrap I mean take your already "cast" points and uniformly randomly resample them and recompute the mean, and do it a few hundred times, and look at how your pile of recomputed means varies.  Call that a step, ad a new sampling on the geometric shape, and then re-bootstrap the set there.  You can see the autocorrelation that Thomas is talking about in the bootstrapping.

Comment: The first part makes sense. I'm trying to understand the use of bootstrapping. Am I correct the idea is to use the random resampling with replacement to approximate the sample (and also true?) distribution so that we can see the variance from pi for every 1000 throws in a single experiment. I'm not sure where the autocorrelation comes in, wouldn't the random resampling at each point get rid of the "shared history" so it would actually show no correlation?

Comment: So the set up is you have had 100 points to put into the domain and used to estimate the pie. There are two ways to bootstrap it. The purest bootstrapping does not move any of the points. You would uniformly randomly select them based on index, and then re-compute. The second way would be to re-spread them in the domain and computer again. These two are going to have very different results. The second method will be much wider and represent the non-correlated estimate.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. Also, in retrospect I think our whole conversation about sample size was backwards. Your intuition was correct. Looking at Thomas' throw number it seems like it takes 6e4 throws (or points) before the answer converges to second significant digit of Pi. However, my objective was to compute the standard error/CI, which should reflect the larger variance associated with smaller sample sizes. So the sample size is kind of irrelevant to this specific problem. Your second suggestion of bootstrapping (with "re-spreading") was the right answer though.

Comment: There is a quote: the unreasonable effectiveness of big data.  It couples with what Nasim Taleb calls a gray swan, in that we think we know things better than we actually do and when something that is actually good is made, it is considered counter-intuitive or unreasonable.  Imagine what things we think we know in more complex areas than 2 digits of pi where we have only a few or a few hundred samples.  We can't imagine how little we know.

Comment: @EngrStudent well said. And just to be clear, I wasn't criticizing the suggestion to increase sample size, it provided a lot of insight to me about precision. I'm just trying to clarify why it was tangential since I myself was very confused about the role sample size had to play in determining better confidence intervals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard error that you want is the standard deviation of the estimate $\hat\pi$ at a fixed point in the sequence, *over multiple experiments*.  This standard error will give you a confidence interval that includes the actual value $\pi$ in 95% of experiments.  You *don't* need a huge sample size to get reasonable estimation of the standard error; you need a huge sample size to get an accurate estimate of $\pi$.

I'm going to do the code in R; translating to Python is left as an exercise for the reader.

First, let's have a look at multiple runs: 100 runs of a 1000-step simulation

```r
hatpi <- function(n){
    x <- runif(n)
    y<-runif(n)
    in_circle<- (x*x+y*y)<=1
    estimate_path<-4*cumsum(in_circle)/(1:n)
    estimate_path
}

plot(1:1000,hatpi(1000),type="l",lwd=2,ylab=expression(pi),xlab="throws",ylim=c(2,4))

for(i in 2:10){
    lines(1:1000,hatpi(1000),col="#00000080")
}
abline(h=pi,col="red")
```

[image]

You can see that the variation along each curve (which is what your first method uses) is smaller than the variation between the curves.  That's because points on the same curve are correlated: the estimates at 800 and 900 throws share the first 800 throws and so have a correlation of 800/900, or nearly 0.9. Your standard error formula didn't take this into account

Now, I'll run a slightly larger set of experiments, 100, and estimate the standard deviation at 100,200,...,1000 throws

```r
experiments<-matrix(0, ncol=10, nrow=100)
for(i in 1:100){
  one_experiment<-hatpi(1000)
  experiments[i,]=one_experiment[100*(1:10)]
}
stddevs <- apply(experiments,2,sd)
lines(100*(1:10), pi-1.96*stddevs,col="purple")
lines(100*(1:10), pi+1.96*stddevs,col="purple")
```

[image]

The standard deviations look more plausible now; the $\pm 1.96$ interval around the true value covers all 10 curves nearly all the way from 100 to 1000 (so the corresponding intervals around each curve would cover the true value).

We can actually do the calculations analytically here. The variance of the binary `in_circle` variable is $(\pi/4)\times(1-\pi/4)$, so the standard deviation of the estimate of $\pi$ based on $n$ throws is $4\sqrt{(\pi/4)\times(1-\pi/4)/n}$

```r
truesd<-function(n) 4*sqrt((pi/4)*(1-pi/4)/n)

stddevs/truesd(100*(1:10))
 [1] 1.071722 1.015365 1.081009 1.090563 1.048619 1.043178 1.023968 1.042759 1.071379
[10] 1.115733
```

Even 100 experiments gave a reasonable estimate of the standard errors. Estimating the standard errors is relatively easy, because you'll probably be happy with the standard error being within about 10% of the truth, but you're trying to get $\pi$ to much more than one digit accuracy.

Now, a larger simulation: 1000 experiements with 100,000 throws each (but plotting only every 1000th throw)

```r
experiments<-matrix(0, ncol=100, nrow=1000)
for(i in 1:1000){
  one_experiment<-hatpi(100000)
  experiments[i,]=one_experiment[1000*(1:100)]
}
stddevs <- apply(experiments,2,sd)

plot((1:100)*1000,experiments[1,],type="l",lwd=2,ylab=expression(pi),xlab="throws",ylim=c(3,3.3))
for(i in 2:10){
    lines(1000*(1:100),experiments[i,],col="#00000080")
}

lines(1000*(1:100), pi-1.96*stddevs,col="green",lwd=2)
lines(1000*(1:100), pi+1.96*stddevs,col="green",lwd=2)
lines(1000*(1:100), pi-1.96*truesd(1000*(1:100)),col="orange",lty=2,lwd=2)
lines(1000*(1:100), pi+1.96*truesd(1000*(1:100)),col="orange",lty=2,lwd=2)
```

[image]

I've only drawn 10 of the experiments, but you can still see the pattern. The estimated and analytic standard errors are almost identical (the green and orange curves are superimposed) and 9 of the 10 lines stay inside the interval.

The standard error is only 0.005 after 100,000 throws, so you'll need many more than that for a good value of $\pi$. The confidence intervals were well estimated with only 100 experiments, and 1000 experiments is overkill.

Finally, could you estimate the standard error from a single run? Yes, you could, but not the way you were doing it.  Averages (and variances) *of the binary `in_circle` variable* along one run estimate the same thing as averages and variances across experiments. But averages and variances of the cumulative estimator don't -- they're increasingly correlated.

```r
hatpi_with_sd<-function(n){
    x<-runif(n)
    y<-runif(n)
    in_circle<- (x*x+y*y)<=1
    estimate_path<-4*cumsum(in_circle)/(1:n)
    estimate_sd <-4*sd(in_circle)
    estimate_se <-estimate_sd/sqrt(1:n)
    list(estimate_path,estimate_se)
}

experiment<-hatpi_with_sd(1000)
plot(1:1000,experiment[[1]],type="l",lwd=2,ylab=expression(pi),xlab="throws",ylim=c(2,4))
lines(1:1000, experiment[[1]]-1.96*experiment[[2]],col="red")
lines(1:1000, experiment[[1]]+1.96*experiment[[2]],col="red")
abline(h=pi,col="purple")
```

[image]

It works!  The bootstrap idea is a slightly more general version of this, where the `estimate_sd` is based on empirical standard deviations over intervals of more than one time point, so it would work for, eg, autocorrelation estimates as well as for means.

Comment: Great answer! This has clarified a lot of theoretical and implementation confusion that I haven't been able to answer after days of looking online. I'm going to have to read it a couple more times to absorb the details, but this line alone "the estimates at 800 and 900 throws share the first 800 throws and so have a correlation of 800/900, or nearly 0.9" clarifies a lot.

Comment: I have some follow-up questions: In examples 2 and 3 where you're plotting the CIs for multiple experiments with 1000 and then 100,000 throws, why aren't you dividing the `stddevs` with the square root of the number of experiments at that point? I see `pi-1.96*stddevs`, but shouldn't it be `pi-1.96*stddevs/range(1,experiment_number)`?

Comment: Second question: You say that "Averages (and variances) of the binary in_circle variable along one run estimate the same thing as averages and variances across experiments." but wouldn't the correlation of `in_circle` at throw 800 and 900 also share the same first 800 points and thus have a correlation of 0.9? Why isn't this more correlated like the cumsum?

Comment: `in_circle` isn't correlated, it's just independent results of each throw.  The reason not to scale `stddevs` by $1/\sqrt{n}$ is that it's already the standard deviation of the independent $\hat\pi$ estimates from different experiments, so it already gets smaller as they get closer together.

Comment: Beautiful work.  For a moment I was wondering if it was whuber or gung writing the answer.  You might want to show what log10 scaling the x-axis does to the shape of the convergence in the 2nd to the last plot.

Comment: @ThomasLumley, okay I see my mistake, the sample SD estimate: `estimate_sd <-4*sd(in_circle)` is a scalar value, I was thinking it was producing a vector of cumulative SDs for every ith-step of `in_circle`'s N length (like cumsum). I see it's not correlated.

Comment: I am still puzzled by how the variance of `in_circle` is used to derive the population SD of $\pi$.  If `in_circle` sample variance is $\sigma_{sample}^2 = (\pi/4)×(1−\pi/4)$; population variance is $\sigma_{pop}^2 = \sqrt{\sigma_{sample}^2/n}$. Your formula then scales this by 4 to represent population SD of $\pi$  `4*sqrt((pi/4)*(1-pi/4)/n)`, but we calculate $\pi$ by calculating proportion of `in_circle` points to $n$, shouldn't we be scaling $\sigma_{pop}^2$ by $4/n$ not $4$? Or to put it another way: how does the variance of `in_circle` map to the variance of $\pi$?

Comment: `estimate_sd` is the population sd of the individual throw estimates of $\pi$, which are either 4 or 0. `estimate_se`, which divides by `sqrt(1:n)` is the standard  error of $\hat\pi$ after $n$ throws.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasLumley, I think I understand it now, I didn't recognize that the mean of `in_circle` is equal to `sum(in_circle)/N` because it's a binary vector. Thus the `in_circle` values are a sample from the uniform distribution, with a true pop. mean of $\pi/4 = 0.785$. Since the `estimate_se` represents the standard deviation of the **mean** of the sample, we don't need to divide by N (it's already normalized because it's a binary variable). The sample sd here approximates the population sd (`estimate_sd`), which is constant, so the only array of values is the `sqrt(1:n)`.